# Flutter getters issue

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I have an issue with my code

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    class UserModel {
      static const NAME = 'name';
      static const EMAIL = 'email';
      static const ID = 'id';
    
       String _name;
       String _email;
       String _id;
    
      //getters
      String get name => _name;
      String get email => _email;
      String get id => _id;
    
      UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
  _name = snapshot.data[NAME];
    _email = snapshot.data[EMAIL];
    _id = snapshot.data[ID];
    
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error.

> Non-nullable instance field '_email' must be initialized. Try adding
> an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this
> constructor, or mark it
> 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field Non-nullable
> instance field '_name' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer
> expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it
> 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field Non-nullable
> instance field '_id' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer
> expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it
> 'late'.dartnot_initialized_non_nullable_instance_field

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpnKe.png) Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the error in 2 ways:

**Option 1:**

Ensure the fields dont get assigned to `null`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  static const NAME = 'name';
  static const EMAIL = 'email';
  static const ID = 'id';

  String _name = NAME;
  String _email = EMAIL;
  String _id = ID;

  //getters
  String get name => _name;
  String get email => _email;
  String get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    _name = snapshot?.data[NAME] ?? "Predefined Name";
    _email = snapshot?.data[EMAIL] ?? "Predefined email";
    _id = snapshot?.data[ID] ?? "Predefined Data";
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Declare the fields as nullable so they can be assigned to null in future

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  static const NAME = 'name';
  static const EMAIL = 'email';
  static const ID = 'id';

  String? _name = NAME;
  String? _email = EMAIL;
  String? _id = ID;

  //getters
  String? get name => _name;
  String? get email => _email;
  String? get id => _id;

  UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    _name = snapshot?.data[NAME]; //snapshot or snapshot.data[NAME] may be null
    _email = snapshot?.data[EMAIL];
    _id = snapshot?.data[ID];
  }
}
```

In your code, `_name` is non-nullable field meaning it needs to be initialized with some value and in future also it cannot be assigned to null or to any varibale which can be null. Otherwise `_name` should be explicitely declared to hold null. The fix can be to ensure that this rule satisfied

Comment: I have added the last three missing lines, so there is where i am getting an error

Comment: I am getting this two errors:..The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'. AND The receiver can't be null, so the null-aware operator '?.' is unnecessary.
Try replacing the operator '?.' with '.'

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a field as:

```
String _name
```

This means `_name` *must* be a String, and cannot be `null`. However in your constructor you have not assigned a value to `_name`, which means it's possible to construct a `User` where `_name` is not set (and would be null) and is therefore invalid.

You either need to ensure `_name` is assigned in the constructors initializer, or you should define the fields as `String?` (which means they can be `String` or `null`).

You can find more information about non-nullability in Dart at https://dart.dev/null-safety.